# Referencing by file identifier in IsoDep tag

Tags: android, nfc, apdu

I am trying to write data into IsoDep tags. The memory of an IsoDEP tag is organized in a structural hierarchy:

- DFs (Dedicated Files)
- EFs (Elementary Files)

Before writing something into a tag, I use the `SELECT` command (in APDU commands set). I want to select a file by `file identifier`, but I don't know any file identifier in a tag.

How can I get all file identifiers existing in a tag?

Answer (score 1):

If your card is ISO 7816-4 compliant, then it will have an MF (file identifier 3F00) which is the root directory. Under this you should find EFiccid (2FE2) and EFdir (2F00) on most cards.

*Edit* : to answer the question, there is no standard APDU to list files within a card, each vendor has proprietary APDUs for this.